# Google Script: Creating a Folder After Form Submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

This is the first time I am writing a Google Script. I've never written JavaScript, but I do have experience in Java and Python. The goal I have with this script is once a Form is submitted, I'd want the script to create a folder that is named using one of the answers to a multiple choice question. The folder should be placed in the same directory as where the Form is located. My Google Script so far consists of the following:

```
function createFolder(e) {
  var existingForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  if(e){
    var response = e.response;
    var items = response.getItemResponses();
    DriveApp.createFolder(items[1].getResponse());
  }
}

function createSubmitTrigger(){
  var existingForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createFolder').forForm(existingForm).onFormSubmit().create();
}
```

This is a bounded script to a Form that I've already created. I've ran my script from within the script editor and didn't receive any errors. I also submitted a response on my own to the Form, but a new folder was not created. The execution transcript shows that the script performed the `getActiveForm()` function, but nothing past that. Hence, I believe it's not stepping into the 'if' statement that I have on my 3rd line. I'm sure that there's something fundamental that I'm missing, but I'm not quite sure what it is. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

By the way, I did look in my inbox to see if I received an error message for the trigger, but I did not see anything.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of e before checking it, to make sure the right event is being sent?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass parameters to a trigger function.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow what you're saying. Doesn't the 'e' variable get created once the form is submitted? Hence, the `createSubmitTrigger` function should run once the form is submitted and `createFolder` should inherit `e` from `createSubmitTrigger`. Am I not not understanding that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you use a trigger ?
you can use the Folder class in your script.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addFolder(Folder)

```
var folders = DriveApp.addFolder("link in your Google Drive");
```

Comment: I am using a trigger because I want the new folder to only be created after the form is submitted. So I'm not sure if what you're proposing would work for me. . .

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
function createFolder(e) {
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses()
  var name = items[1].getResponse();
  new_folder = DriveApp.createFolder(name);

  var submittedID = items[3].getResponse();

  for (i = 0; i < submittedID.length; i++) { 
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(submittedID[i]);
    file.makeCopy(new_folder);
  }
}
```

Creates a new folder and puts the files (images, audio, whatever) that are uploaded in response three in a new folder. My second response becomes the name of the new folder. In this way you can easily distinguish between the files that are uploaded for each submission instead of having them all in the same folder.

Not **exactly** what you are asking for but really close.

Answer (score 0):

Right. So here is my penny worth. I am by no stretch experienced but I managed to crack this one after some serious nerves.

1. on form submit user uploads file which, by default, goes to the form responses folder
2. using the script below, one has the chance to define a source folder and create an additional folder bearing the name of one of the form answers. The parent folder (sourceFolder) can be any folder including the original google form folder; just get the unique id from the URL and paste it in line 4
3. then a copy of the uploaded file is added to said folder and Bob's your uncle

   ```
   function createFolder(e) {
     var items = e.response.getItemResponses()
     var documentName = items[0].getResponse(); 
     var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('copy and paste parent folderid here');                                                                        
     var new_folder = sourceFolder.createFolder(documentName);

     var submittedID = items[3].getResponse(); 

     for (var i = 0; i < submittedID.length; i++) { 
       var file = DriveApp.getFileById(submittedID[i]);
       file.makeCopy(new_folder);
     }
   }
   ```

One big headache is the finding of answers in the google spreadsheet using the items[i] way where i can be quite a fickle thing but it finally worked. To make sure that you do not end up with empty folders make sure all the questions are mandatory before the user actually uploads the document. Hope this helps somebody

I don't want/need to do this but if you want to delete the original uploaded file then use the `[setTrashed(True)][1]`. Add that under file.makeCopy before you close the "for" loop. Just note that if you do this the link in the responses spreadsheet will not work but you will have the copy of the uploaded file in the child folder.